# Sonar complaining "SonarQube analysis is already in progress"

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to run Sonar analysis via Maven, but it continually complains:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project mio-commons: Another SonarQube analysis is already in progress for this project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

There is no analysis for this project in progress, and I've even tried deleting the project itself from Sonar. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Can you please add more details? What SonarQube version? Which command did you run? Does it happen for other projects or only this one?

Comment: Unfortunately, deleting `~/.sonar/cache` and `.scannerwork` did not help. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved it, I guess, deleting `${basedir}/.sonar` folder.

Comment: I also killed all java.exe processes.

Answer (score 6):

For me, deleting `${projectDir}/.scannerwork` fixed the problem.

Command on linux:

```
$ <your project directory>
$ rm -rf .scannerwork
```

I am using sonarqube version 7.0 and sonar-scanner version 3.0.3.778

Answer (score 5):

The cache directory is displayed in the console logs. Deleting that worked for me.
For me, it was under

```
 C:\Users\<username>\.sonar\cache
```